# Shopify Flow - Image Filters

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to setup a Flow that sends an internal email when there is a special order - triggered by Shopify Flow.

Everything works except the image URLs.

Traditionally in Liquid + HTML, you can write:

```
{{ product| img_url: '200x200' }}
{{ product.image | img_url: '200x200' }}
{{ product.featuredImage | img_url: '200x200' }}
{{ product | image_url: width: 200, height: 200 }}
```

I am trying to do the same in Shopify Flow, but none of it works, and the documentation doesn't have anything about images.

They do specify that:

"If no transform options are specified, then the original image will be preserved including any pre-applied transforms."

I have found the documentation for this... but only for [GraphQL](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2022-10/input-objects/ImageTransformInput). There are zero examples on Shopify Flow.

Right now, this is what I have, but it's rendering the image at full size. I can resize it with CSS, but these will very quickly take up my email storage space:

```
{% for item in order.lineItems %}
  <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" /> // <--------- HERE
{{ item.title}} - {{ item.sku }} - {{ item.quantity }}
{% endfor %}
```

These are the error codes that I got:

```
Liquid error: undefined filter img_url
Liquid error: undefined filter product_img_url
Liquid error: undefined filter img_tag
Liquid error: undefined filter img_tag_url
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tried the src instead of URL?

Comment: If those filters are not supported, you probably need to build the URL yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Paul for the comments.

I added string filters to build the url:

```
{{ item.image.url | replace: '.png', '_100x100.png' | replace: '.jpg', '_x100x100.jpg'}}
```

This works just fine for emails.